# paypal recurring payment work in sandbox but not in live

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i am testing PayPal recurring payment in my web the same code work for me in sandbox but when i change the url to make them live i get this error

```
Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3 and T3 parameters for a subscription.
```

this is the code that i am testing

```
<form name="frm_payment_method" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mymail@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.domain.com/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.domain.com/cancel.html">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.domain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Monthly Subscription">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="80">
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M">
</form>
```

when i try this in sandbox url it work

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

but when i make them live

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

i got this error

Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3 and T3 parameters for a subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a line below.

Also make sure the value of 'business' is the email address of your Live PP acct instead of Sandbox PP acct.